# Why not use Oracle SecureFile LOB

Tags: oracle

I am thinking of using SecureFile LOB because it seems to be a great technology to store binary data inside the DB. Is there any disadvantage to using this technology? I have been researching but have only found its advantages

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Even if I am working with the Enterprise version of Oracle, do I have to pay something extra?

Comment: AFAIK, only if you compress or deduplicate (+$11500) or encrypt (+$15000) your LOBs. See https://www.oracle.com/assets/technology-price-list-070617.pdf

Answer (score 0):

SecureFile LOBs are newer (11.1, 2009) and allow compression, deduplication and encryption. SecureFile LOBs are free, but the three features need extra licenses. The selling point is smaller, safer, faster.

BasicFile LOBs are older (8i, 1999), and IMHO there is a good reason why Oracle introduced a completely new implementation of LOBs only 10 years later, they where just terribly slow.

I believe that the underlying technology is quite good. At work we use them for quite a while with good results.

The only drawback in my opinion is that you cannot shrink a SecureFile segment.

Comment: Sorry, bad English. I think the BasicFile implementation was just bad, SecureFiles are much better designed. That is not enough to convince customers to adopt SecureFiles, Oracle needed other points (like compression, encryption) to "sell" it to the user.